# js password generator, how can i combine returned values in a string

Tags: javascript

So what I'm trying to do is, generate a random character/number and concat it to a string and combine them together. I can get a random character/number with above code but can't figure out how to join them in a string. `len` is entered by the user which represents the length of the string(so if 5 is entered, the random string needs to be 5 characters long)

```js
    function createPassword() {
        var len= document.getElementById('length').value;

        for (let i=0; i<len.length; i++) {
            var random= Math.floor(Math.random()*94)+33
            var char = String.fromCharCode(random)
            var password=''
            password+=char[i]

            console.log(password)
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does this line `var password=''` do? How does this affect the expected output?

Comment: `i < len.length` should probably be `i < len`. If someone enters "6", presumably you want a 6 character password, not 1 (i.e. `"6".length == 1`).

Comment: creates a new empty string, what i want to do is get the random characters and put it in password variable

Comment: i < len.length should probably be i <= len

Answer (score 3):

You just need to declare password variable outside the loop

- len supped to be number, so don't need len.length, just len in for
- char[i] - just use char, so we can make it one-line, without actual char variable
  password+=String.fromCharCode(random)

I suggest supplying len as an argument, so just call

```
console.log( createPassword(16) )
```

Here function itself

```
function createPassword(len){
    var password = '';//declare

    for(let i=0; i<len; i++){
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*94)+33
        password += String.fromCharCode(random)
    }

    return password;
}
```

Comment: I've also improved answer, len is an argument now - createPassword(16)

Comment: @ertemishakk if this was the right answer for you ? do accept as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', createPassword)

function createPassword(){
    var len= document.getElementById('length').value;
    var password=''

    for(let i=0; i<len; i++){
        var random= Math.floor(Math.random()*94)+33
        password+= String.fromCharCode(random)
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerText=password;
}
```

here is the working version of what I was trying to do, for future reference.

It generates a password with random characters/ numbers with inputted lenght